# Can't center a div container

Tags: jquery, html, css, containers, center

I'm trying to center my main container, but whatever I do it still floats left...
The reason I am placing all of my content in a own Div, is that i use a Jquery cycle background, and I want to separate my content from my background. But as mentioned I really cant make my Div container center... 
I hope someone a bit more skilled than me can figure this out!

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Forside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-    1.6.3.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"                src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
        <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade,     scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            pager: '#smallnav', 
            pause:   1, 
            speed: 1800,
            timeout:  3500 
            });         
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bx-overlay">
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="san diego"/>
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="bridge"/>
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="mountains"/>
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="waves"/>
        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="americanflag"/>
        <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="football"/>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        <img src="images/header.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

and this is my css:

```
#slideshow, img.bgM { 
min-height: 100%; 
min-width: 1024px; 
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
z-index:-9999; 
}
.bx-overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: transparent url(images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
z-index:-1;}
#container{
position: absolute;
text-align:center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}
#header {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: absolute;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: you can't use absolute positioning with margin:auto, if you need z-indexing to apply, use relative positioning

Comment: Applying text-align:center to the div centers the content inside the div. If you want to horizontally center the div itself, you need to set text-align:center to the div's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this as your HTML

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <img src="images/header.png">
    </div>
```

The container will be 100% fo the width of it's parent

To center the header

```
#header {
display: block; <-- not required as it's a div 
margin-left: auto; <-- not required as it's a overridden by last margin property 
margin-right: auto; <-- not required as it's a overridden by last margin property 
position: absolute; <-- remove this  
text-align:center; <-- only required if you are centering text
margin:0 auto; <-- this will center provided you add a width OR max-width
width: add a value;
}
```